# Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User | undefined'

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, schema, document

Hey y'all I'm getting an error "Property '_doc' does not exist on type 'User & { _id: ObjectId; }" in one of my controllers document for getting a specific user. I am using Mongoose + Typescript for my backend database. My original interface did not extend the Document class. After doing some research I found that I needed to extend my interface to Document class, which I did. I'm simply just trying to get my user's info back and I'm not sure how to do so.

This is my current User model(left) and controller(right) file:
[image: My current file setup]

UPDATE: I made a minor update and added the following to my model file:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

export interface UserResult<T> extends mongoose.Document {
  _doc: T;
}

export interface User extends UserResult<User> {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

const UserSchema = new Schema<User>({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
});

export default model<User>('User', UserSchema);
```

It fixed the aforementioned error, however, I am now faced with a new error: "Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User | undefined'." I definitely have a password property on my User model. Any quick fixes or recommendations?

This is my new file setup after fixing original bug:
[image: New File setup]

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be getting that error from your object destructuring statement here:

```
const {password, ...others} = user?._doc
```

Since you're using optional chaining on `user?._doc`, if `user` is `undefined`, the expression will resolve to `undefined`, and password can't be destructured from `undefined`. You can directly access the password using optional chaining (`const password = user?._doc?.password`), which would be undefined if either `user` or `user._doc` is nullish. Also, if you're not using the `others` object, you actually don't need to destructure it out like you might need to in other languages, you can just say `const {password} = user._doc`

Comment: I fixed the bug by doing something similar: I will post it below.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the bug by simply adding the following to my controller file:

```
export const getUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!!user) {
      const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
      res.status(200).json(others);
    }
  } catch(e) {
    res.status(500).json(e);
  }
};
```

basically IF the user exists, do the following...